# Django quiz app: attribute error

Tags: python, django

The error happens when trying to take a quiz. Although the attribute error of my page is the same as [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995417/django-attribute-error-int-object-has-no-attribute-essay-question-django), the solution has not solved my problem.

I've tried the solution mentioned in the topic above but it hasn't solved my problem. I've mixed all the apps in that Django Quiz in one, having the models in the same file and so on. For the moment it has worked properly, and I've been able to manage the settings in the 'admin' page without any problem.

The issue relies on when taking the quiz, I recieve this traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /myquiz/take/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\P4\myapp\models.py", line 359, in user_sitting
    sitting = self.get(user=user, quiz=quiz, complete=False)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\query.py", line 387, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
myapp.models.DoesNotExist: Sitting matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\P4\myapp\views.py", line 163, in dispatch
    self.quiz)
  File "C:\P4\myapp\models.py", line 361, in user_sitting
    sitting = self.new_sitting(user, quiz)
  File "C:\P4\myapp\models.py", line 339, in new_sitting
    questions = ",".join(map(str, questions_set)) + ","
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\model_utils\managers.py", line 80, in iterator
    sub_obj = self._get_sub_obj_recurse(obj, s)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\model_utils\managers.py", line 153, in _get_sub_obj_recurse
    node = getattr(obj, rel)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'essay_question'
```

It seems like the problem might be in essay_question model or in Sitting model. However, I can't find an answer to this problem. Here there are the pieces of code I think that are related with the error, but if more are needed just ask (most of the parts remain the same of the Quiz app of Django).

**Sitting manager model**:

```
class SittingManager(models.Manager):

    def new_sitting(self, user, quiz):
        if quiz.random_order is True:
            questions_set = quiz.questions_set.all() \
                                            .select_subclasses() \
                                            .order_by('?')
        else:
            questions_set = quiz.questions_set.all() \
                                            .select_subclasses()

        questions_set = questions_set.values_list('id', flat=True)

        if questions_set.count() == 0:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('Question set of the quiz is empty. '
                                       'Please configure questions properly')

        if quiz.max_questions and quiz.max_questions < questions_set.count():
            questions_set = questions_set[:quiz.max_questions]

        questions = ",".join(map(str, questions_set)) + ","

        new_sitting = self.create(user=user,
                                  quiz=quiz,
                                  question_order=questions,
                                  question_list=questions,
                                  incorrect_questions="",
                                  current_score=0,
                                  complete=False,
                                  user_answers='{}')
        return new_sitting

    def user_sitting(self, user, quiz):
        if quiz.single_attempt is True and self.filter(user=user,
                                                       quiz=quiz,
                                                       complete=True)\
                                               .exists():
            return False

        try:
            sitting = self.get(user=user, quiz=quiz, complete=False)
        except Sitting.DoesNotExist:
            sitting = self.new_sitting(user, quiz)
        except Sitting.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            sitting = self.filter(user=user, quiz=quiz, complete=False)[0]
        return sitting
```

And the **QuizTake view**:

**EDITED**

I would appreciate an answer since it's not the same solution of the other similar error with this app. I would provide more needed info and thank you for the help.

.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm getting this now while trying to get to 'myquiz/take' view:

```
Internal Server Error: /myquiz/take/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\P4\myapp\views.py", line 171, in dispatch
    return super(QuizTake, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 213, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\P4\myapp\views.py", line 206, in get_context_data
    context = super(QuizTake, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 122, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 35, in get_form_with_form_class
    return get_form(self, form_class=form_class)
  File "C:\P4\myapp\views.py", line 184, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'question'
```

Here are extracts of my views.py (which seem to be causing the error):

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])
        if self.quiz.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
            raise PermissionDenied

        self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated()

        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.sitting = Sitting.objects.user_sitting(request.user,
                                                        self.quiz)
        else:
            self.sitting = self.anon_load_sitting()

        if self.sitting is False:
            return render(request, 'single_complete.html')

        return super(QuizTake, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Get_form**:

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.questions = self.sitting.get_first_questions()
            self.progress = self.sitting.progress()
        else:
            self.questions = self.anon_next_questions()
            self.progress = self.anon_sitting_progress()

        if self.questions.__class__ is Essay_Questions:
            form_class = EssayForm

        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(QuizTake, self).get_form_kwargs()

        return dict(kwargs, questions=self.questions)
```

**FORM_VALID and get_context_data**

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.form_valid_user(form)
            if self.sitting.get_first_questions() is False:
                return self.final_result_user()
        else:
            self.form_valid_anon(form)
            if not self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]:
                return self.final_result_anon()

        self.request.POST = {}

        return super(QuizTake, self).get(self, self.request)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuizTake, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['question'] = self.questions
        context['quiz'] = self.quiz
        if hasattr(self, 'previous'):
            context['previous'] = self.previous
        if hasattr(self, 'progress'):
            context['progress'] = self.progress
        return context
```

Comment: I can't understand that -1. Can someone tell me instead of picking the low arrow and keep going? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253924/what-to-do-when-the-question-you-want-to-ask-is-a-duplicate?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

> myapp.models.DoesNotExist: Sitting matching query does not exist.

This means exactly what it says. YOu are trying to fetch a Sitting object that does not exist. So you need to sorround line 359 with `try except` to handle that situation cleanly. In fact you can simplify that whole method as follows.

```
def user_sitting(self, user, quiz):
    if quiz.single_attempt is True and self.filter(user=user,
                                                   quiz=quiz,
                                                   complete=True)\
                                           .exists():
        return False

    try:
        return self.filter(user=user,quiz=quiz,complete=True)[0]
    except IndexError:
        return sitting = self.new_sitting(user, quiz)
```

Simpler code is easier to maintain and you are cutting down the number of queries, which leads to a performance improvement.

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'essay_question'

What this means is that you think you h have a `Questions` instance but what you actually have is a meta. The rest of the stacktrace gives you the lines of execution that lead to this error. Look at the lines that mention your own code, some where near they you are calling a method that should return a `Questions` instance but returns int instead.

The reason that it used to work and doesn't work anymore is what's known as a regression error. Changes to some section of code has made another section misbehave. The most popular, sustainable way to tackle them is with unit testing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've edited the first post with the extract of the line 359, where there's already a try except. Isn't it correct to handle the situation?

I've been reviewing the code once and again, and I'm not able to find the method that is returning an int. What could it be, and why? I have no clue of what to change in the lines that mention of my code, I've tried a couple of changes with no success. Thank you

Comment: I also think it's proud to mention that for a while, the /quiz/take page worked (it didnt show an error) but it only showed the plain base.html page (with the styles but without the images nor the jquery loaded) and it didn't respond to any change I was making (it always appeared the same). Now the error appears again. Thank you.

Comment: noted and updated the answer, if you could edit the question and leave only the most relevent bits (about 5 lines before and after the line number in stack trace for example) it might be easier for someone to help.

Comment: Thank you again for the answer. However, the console tells me there are some syntax mistakes in the code you provided

Comment: Well, I think you ought to be able to figure out the syntax errors yourself, I am unable to execute the code because I don't have the full code base.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it as I put in the last edit in the first post. However, it keeps saying that int object has no essay_question attribute. I'm still looking for possible mistakes with no clue. Where is it getting an int? Thank you for your help

Comment: You need some unit tests to make sure Questions instances are returned every place where they are expected. In one place you are getting an int instead of a Questions object

Comment: I've edited the first post with new information about new error while trying to access to 'take' the quiz. Hopefully I'm getting closer to make it work. Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry for late reply. If there are new errors that should really be a new question.